# Resources folder path in cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa

I am working on Mac OS X app which using some c files, and i have a configuration file i add it to the app resources.

My question is "What is the relative path of resources folder?"

I tried

**"[MyAppName].app/Contents/Resources/config.cfg"**

and it works fine only when I run my app from xCode, otherwise it's doesn't work!

I thought the app starts from "MacOS" folder, so i used this path:
**"../Resources/config.cfg"**

but it also didn't work :(

any help please

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using relative paths is asking for trouble. Fortunately Cocoa will give you an absolute path:

```
NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *absPath= [myBundle pathForResource:@"config" ofType:@"cfg"];
```

Comment: I will use this path from c based file, not an objective c.
Thanks

Comment: Look at how you've tagged your question.

Comment: I pass it as a parameter to my c function, thX :)

Comment: You're welcome. I suppose that from a `.c` file, you could make the same call through a series of ObjC runtime function calls, but it would get pretty ugly / unreadable to do it like that.